# Error C#: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, outofrangeexception

I've got a problem with creating objects in a for loop and adding them in a list. The program starts with "How much you want to add?" and whatever I write it shows me a message :  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
What goes wrong? Sorry if there is another similar question but I couldn't find an answer.
Thank you!

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class Animals
{

    public int id { get; set; }


    public string name { get; set; }


    public string color { get; set; }     


    public int age { get; set; }

    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("How much animals you want to add?: ");
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var newAnimals = new List<Animals>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            newAnimals[i].id = i;

            Console.Write("Write name for animal " + i);
            newAnimals[i].name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Write age for animal " + i);
            newAnimals[i].age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Write color for animal " + i );
            newAnimals[i].color = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nAnimals \tName \tAge \tColor");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + newAnimals[i].name + "\t" + newAnimals[i].age + "\t" + newAnimals[i].color);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the initial (and final) size you could also use an `Animals[]`. Then you could initialize the array in your way (via index). If the size could change later you should use the `List<Animals>` and `List<>.Add` to add elements.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't add any items to your list `newAnimals`, it is empty, and thus it has no item on index 0.

Create an instance of `Animal` and then `Add` it (I renamed the class name, since it is a singular):

```
Animal animal = new Animal();

// do you magic

newAnimals.Add(animal);
```

*After* this, you can retrieve the item at index 0.

Answer (score 2):

`var newAnimals = new List<Animals>(count);` creates an empty list with specific [Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) (the total number of elements the internal data structure can hold without resizing)

As it says in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) about this constructor:

> Initializes a new instance of the List class that is empty and has
>   the specified initial capacity.

You need to use [`Add`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj98OuwyafNAhUDDsAKHRYKBBAQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F3wcytfd1(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFjPohK1KEyjc8XIaNLNpQl_-n-wQ&bvm=bv.124272578,d.ZGg&cad=rja) method to add elements to the list.

```
newAnimals.Add (new Animal() {id = 1, name = "name"});
```